# Render content with Vue syntax / component string through AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, dynamic

I have this HTML pattern:

```
<div id="New"> == ajax loaded content == </div>
```

It was easy to render HTML at server side and use innerHTML to inject the content into the right place.
Now I am trying to use Vue.js to do the same thing but render HTML at the client side. I can make this pattern into a component, let's say componentA, with template:

```
componentA  

template:
`<div><slot></slot></div>`
```

It works if the HTML page content is something like:

```
<componentA>
  <componentB></componentB> and some other none component content
</componentA>
```

The componentB is rendered and replaced the slot in componentA.

The problem is how do I use AJAX call (the call is made outside of componentA) to load

```
  <componentB></componentB> and some other none component content
```

into the slot of componentA, and still make componentB to render correctly?
In real situation, the content from AJAX call can be

```
<componentB>, <componentC>, <componentD> ...
```

The following will treat componentB as regular string

```
in HTML:
<componentA>
  <div id="New"></div>
</componentA>

in JS:
document.getElementById('New').innerHTML =
 '<componentB></componentB> And some other none component content';
```

Is there a proper way to render string from AJAX return with Vue syntax as Vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is put the ajax response like `<component></component>` to `Component.template` inside `render` function ([Vue Guide: Render Function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)).

Like below demo:

```js
const Foo = Vue.component('foo', {template: '<p>Foo - {{flag}}</p>', props: ['flag']})
const Bar = Vue.component('bar', {template: '<p>Bar - {{flag}}</p>', props: ['flag']})
const Generic = Vue.component('generic', { 
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement('div', [
      createElement('h3', 'Title'),
      createElement('button', {on: {click: this.loadComponent}}, 'Load Component'),
      this.dynamicComponent
      && createElement(Vue.component('v-fake-slot', {template:this.dynamicComponent, props: ['flag']}), {
        props: {
          flag: this.parent
        }
      }) 
    ])
  },
  props: ['parent'],
  data () {
    return {
      components: ['<foo :flag="flag"></foo>', '<bar :flag="flag"></bar>'],
      index: 0,
      dynamicComponent: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadComponent: function () {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.index += 1
        this.dynamicComponent = this.components[this.index % 2]
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
})



new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      test: 'root'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <generic :parent="test"></generic>
</div>
```

Comment: Now I understand the idea is to treat the AJAX return as a template and create a component out of it. What about props from root data? for example: const Foo = Vue.component('foo', {props:['p_p'], template: '<p>Foo{{p_p}}</p>'})  with  components: ['<div><foo :p_p="index"></foo> AAA</div>', '<bar></bar>'],  gives error. Works without :p_p

Comment: updated the codes, it seems works fine for `'<foo :flag="1"></foo>', '<bar :flag="2"></bar>'`. what is the error you met?

Comment: it works if the prop is a fixed string or number. It fails when I try to use some variable from root data, new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {'Test': 4}
})  and <div id="app">
  <foo :flag="Test"></foo>
  <generic></generic>
</div>. works on the first but not with button clicked. "[Vue warn]: Property or method 'Test' is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: if so, one workaround is add one prop for `v-fake-slot`, then binds that prop with one value from generic component. Check above updated snippet.

Comment: Thanks. It works but kind of very specific to what is going to be loaded. Would be nice if there is a simple way to treat anything loaded through AJAX as if it was in the page before Vue instance was created

Comment: it has some workarounds. the key point is the variables of ancestor components must be accessible in current context. So one way is pass it from the ancestor. another way is put the variables into Vue.prototype.